# How exactly are block rewards calculated in ethereum?

Tags: ether

On some websites the block reward looks like this:2 + 0.9126 + 0.00257 + 0.06867 ETH

Etherescan shows it like this:2 + txfees

So, I think the block reward is a fix amount (2 in 2021) and tx fees.
Or is there any special calculation for the tx fees shown above ?

Cheers

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is a special calculation you are not including, it is the reward for Uncles.

Here is the exact algorithm that does this math:

```
func accumulateRewards(config *params.ChainConfig, state *state.StateDB, header *types.Header, uncles []*types.Header) {
    // Select the correct block reward based on chain progression
    blockReward := FrontierBlockReward
    if config.IsByzantium(header.Number) {
        blockReward = ByzantiumBlockReward
    }
    if config.IsConstantinople(header.Number) {
        blockReward = ConstantinopleBlockReward
    }
    // Accumulate the rewards for the miner and any included uncles
    reward := new(big.Int).Set(blockReward)
    r := new(big.Int)
    for _, uncle := range uncles {
        r.Add(uncle.Number, big8)
        r.Sub(r, header.Number)
        r.Mul(r, blockReward)
        r.Div(r, big8)
        state.AddBalance(uncle.Coinbase, r)

        r.Div(blockReward, big32)
        reward.Add(reward, r)
    }
    state.AddBalance(header.Coinbase, reward)
}
```

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/3708454f58923582585c5a231243324729011a39/consensus/ethash/consensus.go#L626